# Representation theory and special functions

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, special-functions

It is well-known that many special functions arrives from the representation theory of some groups. For example Jacobi polynomials follows from $SU(2)$ group.

Is it any book/article where such relations between special functions and groups are include ?

I am looking for orthogonal polynomials which can be obtained from direct sums or tensor products of the simplest groups of matrices. I need some summary list of such objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion:

> A. U. Klimyk, N. Ya. Vilenkin, *II. Representations of Lie groups and special functions*, in "Representation theory and noncommutative harmonic analysis II", ed. A. A. Kirillov, Springer, (1991), pp. 137-266.